# Insert external file content as HTML through XSLT

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt

i'm a little stucked with some XSLT issue.

I have some simple xml-files and the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:param name="linked_content"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Chapter summary</title>
        </head>
        <body BGCOLOR="white">
            <xsl:value-of select="$linked_content"></xsl:value-of>
        </body>
    </html>             
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The **linked_content** comes from a simple text file (e.g. summary.txt):

```
<p>
Consider this as a simple summary ^^
</p>

<h3>Part One</h3>
```

Now my question: How can i insert the HTML-Code from the text file as HTML code into the resulting html file. I know, the code above wont work, since i only get &gt, &lt in the resulting inserted text.

I'm not stuck to submit the content through a parameter. If their's a way to read the textfile from within the stylesheet, that would great!

Anyone an idea?

**EDIT:**
Still stuck here. I tried a workaround reading the text file in java and setting the content as a parameter to the stylesheet. Sadly the

- <
- >

signs are being translated in the process to &lt and &gt ... thus, the html code is screwed. Is there a chance to force the stylesheet not to transform them?

Thx!

Comment: This question is not about XSLT at all. It is about how to present and process HTML as XML. There are several tools that parse HTML and produce an XML document/fragment from this HTML -- just use one of  these tools.

Comment: It **IS** a XSLT question. I want to insert external code into a transformed document via XSLT. The workaround is a XSLT question too, since the stylesheet automatically escapes at the lt/gt characters! Which, ultimately, got me to the answer: '<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$linked_content"/>' and everything works!

Comment: I'll post the complete solution later... (still not allowed to ^^)

Comment: @Gruber: Eeewww ... DOE is not mandatory to be implemented by an XSLT processor -- exactly because it goes against the architecture of the XSLT processing model. By resorting to DOE you prove absolutely that this is *not* XSLT question.

Comment: I know it's an optional attribute. The original problem lies within the XSLT, the solution too, so explain me again: Why did you remove the xslt flag? ... on the other hand, forget it. Next year's another one. Cheers!

Comment: @Gruber: It is not XSLT's problem that someone want's to make it process non-XML. If your input isn't a well-formed XML document then the problem is clearly this. Just make it well-formed XML or well-formed XML fragment, then your current XSLT code will not need to be modified at all. There is no problem with the XSLT code -- the problem is external to XSLT. Theoretically one could make an XML parser using XSLT, but that is like designing an artificial cow to eat grass and produce milk - a lot of effort and no need to do so, as we already have real, more efficient cows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of problem is messy. You can either treat it as an HTML-to-HTML transformation in which the XSLT processor sees the HTML only as text, or as an HTML-to-HTML transformation in which the XSLT processor sees the HTML as XML. In the first case, you're not going to be able to do much transformation of the content; in the second case, you're exposed to the input not being valid. Either way, it's not the pure XML-to-XML use case for which XSLT was designed, so you're going to need extensions.

The first approach - treating it as text - can be achieved using disable-output-escaping, provided (a) your processor supports it, and (b) you use a processing pipeline in which transformation is immediately followed by serialization.

The second approach - treating it as XML - can be achieved using extensions such as saxon:parse-html() which takes HTML input and converts it to a tree representation of some "equivalent" XML.

Comment: Jap, it is messy! ^^ ... Thanks for your explanations AND possible solutions! -- Cheers :)

Comment: `HTML-to-HTML` is featured twice in the first two lines while one of the four `HTML`s was probably meant to be an `XML`.

Answer (score 3):

Are your html files well-formed?

You can try using 'copy-of' in your xsl.

```
<p><xsl:copy-of select="document('yourHtmlDoc.html')"/></p>
```

If you need specific items out of your html file, you can even set a path, given that your html is well-formed.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('yourHtmlDoc.html')/tagsNeeded"/>
```

Comment: Hi, the document would work, but the html-code in the text files isn't always wellformed (and of course out of my reach ^^)

Answer (score 2):

You can use unparsed-text() function which can read external file in.
Or if you know that the external file is a valid xml, you can use document() function as well.
Both XSLT 2.0 functions however - i think.

Comment: hi, i get compilation errors of the stylesheet when using the unparsed-text() function... no matter if i'm at XSLT2.0 or 1.0