# copy-of with search and replace relative paths

Tags: xslt

I want to insert an html snippet from an external file into my output document with copy-of like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976762/18427492
The html snipped is a navigation bar and also used by other (python) scripts to generate other html files.
I need to replace the path in "href" to match a relative path that i have in a XSLT variable.

Full file content (Template file to be copied):

```xml
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="fineprint">MyNiceGame Developer Mode Documentation</li>
    <li class="switchlang"><a href="../en/content.html"><img src="/deco/dco_en_sml.gif" alt="English" border="0"></img></a></li>
    <li><a href="../../sdk/index.html">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../content.html">Contents</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../search.php">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../sdk/console.html">Engine</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../sdk/cmdline.html">Command Line</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../sdk/files.html">Game Data</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../sdk/script/index.html">Script</a></li>
</ul>
```

So how can i insert this snippet into my XSL document and replace ../../sdk/ (its possible to change this string to something like `{replace-me}/sdk/...`) with a relative path that i already have in a XSLT variable?

My XSLT document (i want to replace the `<xsl:call-template name="nav"/>` with the template file processing):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="3.0" xpath-default-namespace="https://clonkspot.org" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"/>

    <xsl:template match="/clonkDoc">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:call-template name="nav"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="func"/>
                <!-- other possible nodes under /clonkDoc -->
                <xsl:call-template name="nav"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="nav">
        <xsl:param name="relpath" tunnel="yes"/>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="fineprint">
                    <xsl:when test='lang("en")'>>MyNiceGame Developer Mode Documentation</xsl:when>
                </li>
                <!-- Other li elements -->
    </xsl:template>
```

Example source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../../../clonk.xsl"?>
<clonkDoc xmlns="https://clonkspot.org"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="https://clonkspot.org ../../../clonk.xsd" xml:lang="de">
    <func>
        <!-- other nodes -->
    </func>
</clonkDoc>
```

Desired target file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
   <!-- stuff -->
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul class="nav">
         <!-- The corrected li elements with modified a href link -->
      </ul>
    <!-- Other stuff from source file (<func>) -->
      <ul class="nav">
         <!-- The corrected li elements with modified a href link -->
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

Martin Honnen's solution for my specific case with the `xpath-default-namespace`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="3.0" xpath-default-namespace="https://clonkspot.org" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"/>

    <xsl:template match="/clonkDoc">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="doc('file.html')//ul[@class = 'nav']" xpath-default-namespace="" mode="fix-links"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="func"/>
                <!-- other possible nodes under /clonkDoc -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="doc('file.html')//ul[@class = 'nav']" xpath-default-namespace="" mode="fix-links"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode name="fix-links" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template mode="fix-links" match="ul/li/a/@href" xpath-default-namespace="">
        <xsl:message>Value href: <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of></xsl:message>
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="replace(., '../../sdk', 'foobar')"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy-of` makes a a deep copy, if you want to transform input nodes (even only their attribute values) you write templates to do so e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="doc('file.xml')//ul[@class = 'nav']" mode="fix-links"/>`, or, perhaps, as the edit says the snippet with the `ul` is all in the file, use simply `<xsl:apply-templates select="doc('file.xml')" mode="fix-links"/>`, and

```
<xsl:mode name="fix-links" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template mode="fix-links" match="ul/li/a/@href">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="replace(., '../../sdk', $varname)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The `xsl:mode` declaration is XSLT 3 only, in earlier versions declare the identity transformation for that mode e.g.

```
<xsl:template mode="fix-links" match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="fix-links"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

in XSLT 1 or

```
<xsl:template mode="fix-links" match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

in XSLT 2.

[XSLT 3 sample](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22new-sdk%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%3E..%2Fsdk2%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%2F%2Ful%5B%40class%20%3D%20%27nav%27%5D%22%20mode%3D%22fix-links%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Amode%20name%3D%22fix-links%22%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20mode%3D%22fix-links%22%20match%3D%22ul%2Fli%2Fa%2F%40href%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aattribute%20name%3D%22%7Bname%28%29%7D%22%20select%3D%22replace%28.%2C%20%27..%2F..%2Fsdk%27%2C%20%24new-sdk%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Cul%20class%3D%22nav%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20class%3D%22fineprint%22%3EMyNiceGame%20Developer%20Mode%20Documentation%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20class%3D%22switchlang%22%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22..%2Fde%2Fcontent.html%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%22%2Fdeco%2Fdco_de_sml.gif%22%20alt%3D%22German%22%20border%3D%220%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22..%2F..%2Fsdk%2Findex.html%22%3EIntroduction%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22..%2F..%2Fcontent.html%22%3EContents%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22..%2F..%2Fsearch.php%22%3ESearch%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22..%2F..%2Fsdk%2Fconsole.html%22%3EEngine%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22..%2F..%2Fsdk%2Fcmdline.html%22%3ECommand%20Line%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22..%2F..%2Fsdk%2Ffiles.html%22%3EGame%20Data%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22..%2F..%2Fsdk%2Fscript%2Findex.html%22%3EScript%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ful%3E&input-type=XML) (slighly adapted for the demonstration to work with the primary input) outputs

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="fineprint">MyNiceGame Developer Mode Documentation</li>
    <li class="switchlang"><a href="../de/content.html"><img src="/deco/dco_de_sml.gif" alt="German" border="0"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="../sdk2/index.html">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../content.html">Contents</a></li>
    <li><a href="../../search.php">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="../sdk2/console.html">Engine</a></li>
    <li><a href="../sdk2/cmdline.html">Command Line</a></li>
    <li><a href="../sdk2/files.html">Game Data</a></li>
    <li><a href="../sdk2/script/index.html">Script</a></li>
</ul>
```

As for the information in the latest edit that the secondary input document you want to process has elements in no namespace but your primary one has elements in a certain namespace that your XSLT has used as the `xpath-default-namespace`, in that case you need to override that for any selections in the secondary input e.g.

```
<xsl:mode name="fix-links" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template mode="fix-links" match="ul/li/a/@href" xpath-default-namespace="">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="replace(., '../../sdk', $varname)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and if you continue to use the `apply-templates` with an element selector, there as well e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="doc('file.xml')//ul[@class = 'nav']" xpath-default-namespace="" mode="fix-links"/>`.

Comment: i tried it with XSLT 2 and 3 but never got any result back. Then i tested `<xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="doc('file.html')"/></xsl:message>` and got the strings of the file without nodes printed. When i do `<xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="document('developer/templates/navbar-snippet-de.html')//ul"/></xsl:message>` i get no message output. Something seems wrong with the selection. Maybe doc doesn't gieves out the nodes?

Comment: @itsfoobar, I don't get what you are trying with `xsl:value-of` now in your comments, your question talked about using `copy-of` without showing any code explicitly, I assumed you have something like `<xsl:copy-of select="doc('file.xml')//ul[@class = 'nav']"/>` and suggested to replace that with the approach outlined in the answer e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="doc('file.xml')//ul[@class = 'nav']" mode="fix-links"/>`.  Perhaps edit your question and show minimal but complete sample to allow us to reproduce the problem. We also need to see whether the file you load has an XHTML namespace.

Comment: I just changed the question so that it's more clear. The template file that i load has the exact content as shown above. The `xsl:value-of` was just a test on my side to see if i can log any output to console and if i can select a `ul` node in the document (the latter does not seem to work). I tested with `xsl:message` because with `<xsl:apply-templates select="doc('file.xml')//ul[@class = 'nav']" mode="fix-links"/>` i got no output in the target file.

Comment: It is not clear why a selection with e.g. `//ul` should fail unless your XSLT code you have not shown at all so far use `xpath-default-namespace`. But anyway, if you just want to process the full file, you can of course push `<xsl:apply-templates select="doc('file.xml')" mode="fix-links"/>` through that mode.

Comment: Note also that the currently posted snippet use HTML syntax for the empty `img` element (e.g. `<img ..>`) and therefore won't parse as XML with `document` or `doc`.

Comment: You're right i am using `xpath-default-namespace`. As requested i created an example with (hopefully) all relevant information.

Comment: @itsfoobar, see the edit at the end of the answer, basically wherever you select/match elements from the secondary document not using a namespace the XSLT needs `xpath-default-namespace=""`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250777/discussion-between-itsfoobar-and-martin-honnen).